# Ajuda em Get List (Refatoração Código)

Tags: java, jsf-2.2, refatoração

Eu tenho uma classe com 2 atributos:

```
public class Classe(){
 private String conteudo;
 private String tipoConteudo;

 getters...setters..
}
```

Então eu tenho um *ArrayList* com 3 ou mais objetos dessa classe, como eu faço **em uma linha** um `get` de um Objeto específico de um certo conteúdo??

Por exemplo, se eu quero o objeto que o Tipo é azul, em várias linhas seria:

```
Classe objetoFinal;

for(int i;i<List.size();i++){
  if(objetoFinal.tipoConteudo.equals("azul")
     objetoFinal = List.get(i);
}
```

**Então a dúvida é**: como fazer isso **em uma linha** (preciso colocar em uma página JSF :D)

Comment: Você não pode fazer um método com o seu código de pesquisa e depois utilizar ele na outra página?

Comment: Porque deve ser em uma linha? O que esse requisito tem a ver com o JSF?

Comment: Eu recomendaria [uma abordagem funcional](http://functionaljava.org/).

Comment: @MiguelCartagena provavelmente porque ele está querendo usar isso numa expressão (ex.: `${ ... }`) que deve retornar um valor.

Comment: @mgibsonbr se for esse mesmo o caso, a solução do Fábio é perfeita.

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar essa operação em apenas uma linha deve-se colocar o código de busca em um método getter no ManagedBean, vejamos:

```
public class MyBean {
    public Object getObjetoFinal(){
        Object objetoFinal = null;

        for(int i;i<List.size();i++){
            if(objetoFinal.tipoConteudo.equals("azul")
                objetoFinal = List.get(i);
        }

        return objetoFinal;
     }
}
```

Então em uma página JSF coloca-se a expressão em apenas uma linha, veja:

```
    <h:outputText value = "#{myBean.objetoFinal.conteudo}" />
```

Desse modo você terá uma instância ou null caso não seja encontrado um objeto azul.

Comment: Não é melhor usar `for (Classe c : List) {...}`?

Comment: Sim. O for aprimorado é um atalho interessante em Java 6, mas preferi utilizar o trecho de código da própria pergunta para a resposta ficar simples e direta.

Comment: Certo, mas o código original está errado. Deveria ser `if (List.get(i).tipoConteudo.equals("azul"))`. Só deixei essa nota porque o `for` tradicional chamando `size` a cada iteração e depois fazendo um `get(i)` é menos eficiente e deixa o código mais poluído. Fora isso sua resposta está correta.

Answer (score 1):

Em JSF, os dados podem ser recuperados em um facelet (arquivo `.xhtml`) ou mesmo em um JSP através da simples chamadas a métodos *getter* de beans JSF.

Não é necessário criar *expression languages* elaboradas, basta delegar a lógica necessário ao *getter* do *Managed Bean*.

Um ponto a ser considerado é que não há garantia de que um *getter* será chamado apenas uma vez. Se o código executado no *getter* tiver algum custo, por exemplo leitura no banco de dados, deve-se "cachear" o valor em um atributo do bean.

Exemplo:

```java
private List<Classe> list;
public String getListClasses() {
    if (list == null) {
        list = dao.listaClassesDoBanco();
    }
    return list;
}
```

E, no caso de uma operação que faz busca por um atributo, dependendo do custo, poderia-se também criar um mapa cuja chave seja o valor do atributo.

Além disso, se a lista não é alterada na tela ela deve ser carregada uma só vez. Isso pode ser feito como no método acima ou ainda num método anotado com `@PostConstruct`, que é chamado sempre que o bean é recriado no seu devido escopo.

Exemplo:

```java
public class ManagedBean {

    private List<Classe> list = new ArrayList<Classe>();
    private Map<String, Classe> mapaClasse;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        list = dao.listaClassesDoBanco();
    }

    private Map<String, Classe> getMapaClasse() {
        if (mapaClasse == null) {
            mapaClasse = new HashMap<String, Classe>();
            for (Classe c : list) {
                mapaClasse.put(c.tipoConteudo, c);
            }
        }
        return mapaClasse;
    }

    public Classe getObjetoAzul() {
        return getMapaClasse().get("azul");
    }

    ...

}
```

A expressão no seu facelet fica assim:

```
#{managedBean.objetoFinal.objetoAzul}
```

Também é possível acessar o valor do mapa diretamente:

```
#{managedBean.mapaClasse.azul}
```

Ou:

```
#{managedBean.mapaClasse['azul']}
```

Se estiver usando EL 2.2, pode ainda fazer isso:

```java
public Classe getObjetoPorTipoConteudo(String tipoConteudo) {
    return getMapaClasse().get(tipoConteudo);
}
```

E usar a expressão:

```
#{managedBean.getObjetoPorTipoConteudo('azul')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Desculpem a demora por responder, mas consegui solucionar o problema, mas agora eu ja mudei o codigo do projeto e não mais estou utilizando esse trecho do código, mas usei a ideia do primeiro comentario do liobntt

Comment: poste sua resposta em forma de resposta, como se voce estivesse respondendo uma pergunta de uma outra pessoa, pois sua resposta do jeito que está cabe mais como um comentário